# SQL Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I am trying to select a set of data including female and male in 50 states. However, I need to exclude 5 states with both female and male, and one state with female. I'm not sure how to have two conditions in one where statement.

Below is the simple version of the code. The last row of the code is clearly wrong.

I want to say 'I want to exclude data when state code is OR, CA, WA, OH and VA', also 'I want to exclude data when state code is DC and gender is female'.

I hope you can understand what I am trying to ask. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
SELECT * FROM dataset
WHERE state_code NOT IN ('OR','CA','WA','OH','VA)
AND (state_code <> DC AND gender <> female)
```

Comment: Onluy add quote to you select literal SELECT * FROM dataset
WHERE state_code NOT IN ('OR','CA','WA','OH','VA)
AND (state_code <> 'DC' AND gender <> 'female')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most literal translation of your conditions I can think of:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset
WHERE state_code NOT IN ('OR','CA','WA','OH','VA')
AND NOT (state_code = DC AND gender = 'female')
;
```

It is logically equivalent to Remi's answer, as `NOT (X AND Y)` is the same as `(NOT X OR NOT y)`.

Comment: I just tried and it worked. Fantastic! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected query :

```
SELECT * FROM dataset
WHERE state_code NOT IN ('OR','CA','WA','OH','VA')
AND (state_code != 'DC' OR gender != 'female');
```

The `WHERE state_code NOT IN ('OR','CA','WA','OH','VA')`line excludes 5 state_code and the `AND (state_code != 'DC' OR gender != 'female')` line excludes women living in 'DC' state.

Answer (score 0):

This shoult be correct:

SELECT * FROM dataset
WHERE state_code NOT IN ('DC','OR','CA','WA','OH','VA')
OR (state_code == 'DC' AND gender == male)

Comment: That would not filter out "DC female" as they are not in the "NOT IN" list.